# Xamarin forms App wont display either in IOS emulator and Android Emulator

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Hi guys i am new to xamarin form apps and i am currently running my xamarin forms on visual studio 2019 for mac.I have created a sample app with sliders and label and everytime i try to debug in ios or android platform it shows deploying to device and later visual studio community for mac 2019 on the bar beside the simulators and on the emulators all it displays is welcome to xamarin.forms. I have checked so many blogs with no solution ,i would be glad if someone can help.attached is a screenshot of my emulator screen and xaml page.[emulator and xaml screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnzri.jpg)

Comment: that is the default UI provided by the template.  If your UI is not showing then you are doing something wrong.  It would help a great deal if you actually posted some of your code.  But I'd suggest you start by checking the assignment of MainPage in your App class

Comment: Can you please provide some code snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is that your MainPage of the application is still the default one. In the App constructor check if the MainPage is created like this:

```
   public App() 
   {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new gridpage());
   }
```

This is how you set your MainPage.